# In Neverwinter Nights: Enhanced edition do the inflict wounds spells do critical damage?

Tags: neverwinter-nights

Do the inflict wounds series of spells cause critical damage on a critical hit?
I've tried to test this but am unsure about the results? Is there a way for me to test this to get a clear answer? If the answer is "No" then is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

**All the Spells that have a Touch Attack can critical strike**.

With some Spells, instaed of have more damage you can have some scripted unique results.

[Neverwinter Nights Wiki - Critical Hit](https://nwn.fandom.com/wiki/Critical_hit)

Comment: Hi Rick.
I found some extra information as well. Should I just adjust my question or add to it in the comment section?

Comment: Depends if the anserw remains the same or if it change the subject. In the latter case, it's better to create a new post, otherwise you can adjust your question with extra information.

Comment: I've discovered that inflict wound touch attack spells are scripted to not do critical damage.